Iterate over a JSON API Response using Groovy script with parsing the response
I have a JSON Response which I need to loop over in order to perform some actions using Groovy in Oracle CRM.
It looks something like this:
{
    "items": [
        {
            "JeBatchId": 61003,
            "AccountedPeriodType": "MONTH9042232881"
        },
        {
            "JeBatchId": 60004,
            "AccountedPeriodType": "MONTH9042232882"
        },
        {
            "JeBatchId": 60005,
            "AccountedPeriodType": "MONTH9042232883"
        },
        {
            "JeBatchId": 60006,
            "AccountedPeriodType": "MONTH9042232884"
        },
        {
            "JeBatchId": 60007,
            "AccountedPeriodType": "MONTH9042232885"
        },
        {
            "JeBatchId": 60008,
            "AccountedPeriodType": "MONTH9042232886"
        },
        {
            "JeBatchId": 60009,
            "AccountedPeriodType": "MONTH9042232887"
        }
    ]
}

I tried parsing it using groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json) but Oracle CRM does not seems to support import functionality.
Is it possible to do this without importing an library in CRM?

looks like you are missing new keyword - new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json). if not - show the error that you have.
